# Spring 3.0 TransactionProxyFactoryBean preInterceptors AfterReturningAdvice not working

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-aop

I have a requirement to log business activities that can also map to the audit trail data generated. I use Hibernate envers as the audit trail mechanism.

The way I have implemented the activities log is

1. I have service classes that are proxied using concrete classes
   (using CGLIB) and extend TransactionProxyFactoryBean . This is what
   provides the transaction aspect.
2. My method either has the base object carrying the activity data as
   a return type or argument of the service.
3. The assumption is that when I apply a pre-interceptor on the
   *TransactionProxyFactoryBean* ; its *AfterReturningAdvice* method
   should be called after the transaction is completed.

As per my understanding the pre and post interceptors for the *TransactionProxyFactoryBean* should behave as follows based on the assumptions that the interceptors are added on the stack.

1. The pre-interceptors before advice method run
2. Spring starts the transaction
3. The post-interceptors before advice method runs
4. The main service method runs
5. The post-interceptors after returning advice method runs
6. Spring commits the transaction
7. The pre-interceptors after returning advice method runs

However when I de-bugged the application I found that the **pre-interceptor's after returning advice method runs before the transaction is commited**.

Can anyone please guide me as to what am I doing wrong?

**TransactionProxyFactoryBean configuration**

```
<bean id="fqngTransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fqngTxProxyTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager"><ref local="fqngTransactionManager"/></property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
              <props>
                  <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                  <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                  <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                  <prop key="process*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                  <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
              </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

           <bean id="activityLogInterceptor"
        class="com.fuelquest.mothra.activitylogs.interceptors.ActivityLogInterceptor">
        <property name="activityLogPostingService">
            <ref bean="activityLogPostingService" />
        </property>
        <property name="methodList">
            <list>
                <value>save*</value>
                <value>execute*</value>
                <value>calculate*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Activity Interceptor Java file Definition**

```
public class ActivityLogInterceptor implements AfterReturningAdvice {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(ActivityLogInterceptor.class);

    private ActivityLogPostingService activityLogPostingService;
    private List<String> methodList;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void afterReturning(Object returnValue, Method method,
            Object[] methodParams, Object target) throws Throwable {
        // If return type is ActivityLoggingBaseVO
        if (isLoggedMethod(method.getName())) {
.......................
```

**Service Configuration**

```
<bean id="inventoryControlRuleService" parent="fqngTxProxyTemplate">
            <property name="target">
                <bean
                    class="com.fuelquest.mothra.inventorycontrol.service.impl.InventoryControlRuleServiceImpl">
                    <property name="assetService">
                        <ref bean="assetService" />
                    </property>             
                    <property name="pointOfSaleService">
                        <ref bean="pointOfSaleService" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="inventoryService">
                        <ref bean="inventoryService" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="deliveryService">
                        <ref bean="deliveryService" />
                    </property> 
                    <property name="languageCdDao">
                        <ref bean="languageCdDao" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="inventoryBizRulesDao">
                        <ref bean="inventoryBizRulesDao" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="bizRulesResultsDao">
                        <ref bean="bizRulesResultsDao" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="ruleEngineService">
                        <ref bean="ruleEngineService" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="icRuleCalculationDataDao">
                        <ref bean="icRuleCalculationDataDao" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="inventoryControlService">
                        <ref bean="inventoryControlService" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="fqngESBMessagePoster">
                        <ref bean="fqngESBMessagePoster" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="droolsRuleTemplateService">
                        <ref bean="droolsRuleTemplateService" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="uomsDao">
                        <ref bean="uomDao" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                <props>
                    <prop key="calculate*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception</prop>
                    <prop key="execute*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception</prop>
                    <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception</prop>
                    <prop key="f*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                    <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS</prop>
                </props>
            </property>     
            <property name="preInterceptors">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="activityLogInterceptor"/>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

We use the Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter to share the same Hibernate session across the HTTP thread request that comes to the application/web server from GWT.

We also require to have Hibernate sessions available for the cron jobs that are launched using Quartz scheduler. These threads can't use the Hibernate session made available through the OpenSessionInViewFilter and the TransactionProxyFactoryBean proxy that we use to proxy the transactions fails. Hence we needed to use an additional org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNa meAutoProxyCreator to proxy the polling and SV rule service so that they can be called from the Quartz scheduler.

Because we now had 2 transactional proxies for the same bean; Spring functionality like having pre-interceptor etc was not working as expected because the interceptor was applied on the proxy created with **BeanNameAutoProxyCreator** and NOT **TransactionProxyFactoryBean**.

The solution was to move to Spring 2.x transactions using AOP and TX namespace that resulted in creating a single proxy that was utilized by both the OpenSessionInViewFilter and the Quartz scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding matches mine.

Would switching to an Around advice (MethodInterceptor) for ActivityLogInterceptor help?  If that resolves the issue you may have a bug to report.